# How to create a DatePicker from a List of dates

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am learning JavaFX and came across a requirement in my JavaFX application where I want to create a Datepicker using an `ArrayList` of dates. I need to disable all other dates which are not present in this list (dateList). Finally, according to the date selected, I need to render a `ComboBox` with values in `morningSlot` and `eveningSlot`. The structure of the object is as follows.

```
Schedule {
    List<LocalDate> dateList;
    String morningSlot;
    String eveningSlot;
}
```

Comment: Set a dayCellFactory that returns cells whose updateItem method adjusts the cell’s `disable` property accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the same using the below code. Thanks VGR for the input.

```
 final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
                @Override
                public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker)
                {
                    return new DateCell() {
                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
                        {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            setDisable(empty || !dateList.contains(item));
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
```